# junit4 functions

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

how to create generic functions that could be called from each java  test?
In my function startappli I have :

```
public class startappli{

public void testMain (String[] args) 
 {

  String[] logInfos = new String[3];
  logInfos[0] = (String) args[0];
  logInfos[1] = (String) args[1];
 }
  @BeforeClass
    public static void setupOnce() {
        final Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

             entrypointtoGUI.main(new String[]{"arg0 ", "arg1"});

            }
        };
        try {
            thread.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

}
```

in the toto.java , I call the function as follow : startappli.testmain(loginfo)
it doesn't work 
help ?

---

my function: Runner.java contains : 
public class RunAppli {

@BeforeClass
    public static void setupOnce() {
        final Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

```
            Main.main(new String[]{"-rtebase ", "C:\\bin"});

        }
    };
    try {
        thread.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

@Test
 public void test() {

```
    URL path = this.getClass().getResource("../Tester/map.xml");


    System.out.println("Cover: " + cmapURL);




    }

}
```

}
and from my java test TestDemo.java , I call StartAppli THAT launch the appli GUI : RunAppli .setupOnce();
and I get the path to xml file : 
RunAppli .path
should we use @Test in functions ?
any suggession ?
thanks

Comment: Be specific. Rather than "it doesn't work" say what actually happened, and what you expected to happen, and what you are trying to do. Also, your indentation has gone wrong, can you edit it?

Comment: @lamisse you are supposed to accept an answer if it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is that `startappli.setupOnce()` is not executed.

I believe this is because `startappli` contains no `@Test` methods, therefore JUnit does not take it as a test class. Thus `@BeforeClass` is omitted and the function is not executed by JUnit.

A solution could be to put a `@Test` method in this class. Or, if you want it to be called before each Java test method, you should call it explicitly from the `@Before` methods in each of your test classes (or from the `@BeforeClass` methods if you want it to run only once for each test class).

**Note:** `startappli` is not a good name for a Java class, as the convention is that class names should be camel case, e.g. `StartAppli`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a number of things wrong (actually - all)

1. The [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html) say that class names should be uppercase
2. You are calling `testmain()` and `main()` while the method is camelCased - `testMain()`.
3. You should not run a main method in a new thread with JUnit. A JUnit runner takes care of the instantiation.
4. Your testclass should perform tests - i.e. it should have a method annotated with `@Test`

I'd suggest reading the [JUnit manual](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm) before starting.